# selected item in drop-down should display relevant details

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, xml, xslt

I have a xml file that contains some data. I use a xsl file to display the data in the form of a table.

Please check the xml code and xsl code and the screenshot

**xml file**

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="MMDiagnostics.xslt"?>

<MediaMixer>

  <Conference>
    <Name>Test</Name>
    <ConfId>1002</ConfId>
    <CompositeAddress>238.57.0.1</CompositeAddress>
    <CompositePort>48000</CompositePort>
    <CompositeSsrc>243324353</CompositeSsrc>
    <NoOfParticipants>2</NoOfParticipants>

    <Participant>
      <ID1>abc88C</ID1>
      <ID2>0</ID2>
      <ParticipantAddress>192.168.177.45</ParticipantAddress>
      <ParticipantListeningPort>22004</ParticipantListeningPort>
      <MMListeningPort>45004</MMListeningPort>
      <SSRCFromParticipant>316541</SSRCFromParticipant>
      <SSRCFromMM>26481</SSRCFromMM>
    </Participant>

    <Participant>
      <ID1>piy65R</ID1>
      <ID2>0</ID2>
      <ParticipantAddress>192.168.177.45</ParticipantAddress>
      <ParticipantListeningPort>22004</ParticipantListeningPort>
      <MMListeningPort>45004</MMListeningPort>
      <SSRCFromParticipant>316541</SSRCFromParticipant>
      <SSRCFromMM>26481</SSRCFromMM>
    </Participant>   

  </Conference>

  <Conference>
    <Name>Test002</Name>
    <ConfId>1002</ConfId>
    <CompositeAddress>238.57.0.1</CompositeAddress>
    <CompositePort>48005</CompositePort>
    <CompositeSsrc>353324353</CompositeSsrc>
    <NoOfParticipants>2</NoOfParticipants>

    <Participant>
      <ID1>70542151</ID1>
      <ID2>0</ID2>
      <ParticipantAddress>192.168.177.45</ParticipantAddress>
      <ParticipantListeningPort>22004</ParticipantListeningPort>
      <MMListeningPort>45004</MMListeningPort>
      <SSRCFromParticipant>316541</SSRCFromParticipant>
      <SSRCFromMM>26481</SSRCFromMM>
    </Participant>

    <Participant>
      <ID1>70542151</ID1>
      <ID2>0</ID2>
      <ParticipantAddress>192.168.177.45</ParticipantAddress>
      <ParticipantListeningPort>22004</ParticipantListeningPort>
      <MMListeningPort>45004</MMListeningPort>
      <SSRCFromParticipant>316541</SSRCFromParticipant>
      <SSRCFromMM>26481</SSRCFromMM>
    </Participant>
  </Conference>


  </MediaMixer>
```

**xsl file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet  version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>VPGate Media Mixer</title>
        <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0"/>
        <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"/>
        <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, must-revalidate"/>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15"></meta>
        <script src="/Common/common.js\" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style001.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Grid.Default.css" />
      </head>
      <body class="WorkArea">
        <div class="divSummaryHeader" id="SummaryHeader">
          <h1>Media Mixer - VPGate</h1>         
        </div>

        &#160;
        <div class="RadGrid RadGrid_Default" id="SummaryData" style="position:absolute;width:828px;height:510px;overflow:auto">
          <table border="0" class="rgMasterTable rgClipCells" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
            <tr>
              <input type="button" class="formEditBtn" id="SubBtn" value="Refresh" onclick="window.location=window.location;"/> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="rgHeader SummaryTableHdrRow" style="font-weight:bold;" colspan="2">Conference Summary</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table border="0" class="rgMasterTable rgClipCells" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"  >
                  <tr>
                    <td class="rgHeader SummaryTableHdrRow" style="font-weight:bold;">Conference Name</td>
                    <td class="rgHeader SummaryTableHdrRow" style="font-weight:bold;">Conference ID</td>
                    <td class="rgHeader SummaryTableHdrRow" style="font-weight:bold;">Composite Address</td>
                    <td class="rgHeader SummaryTableHdrRow" style="font-weight:bold;">Composite Port</td>
                    <td class="rgHeader SummaryTableHdrRow" style="font-weight:bold;">Composite Ssrc</td>
                    <td class="rgHeader SummaryTableHdrRow" style="font-weight:bold;">No Of Participants</td>
                  </tr>
                  <xsl:if test="MediaMixer!= ''">
                    <xsl:for-each select="MediaMixer/Conference">
                      <!--<xsl:sort select="Name"/>-->
                      <xsl:if test="Name !=''">
                        <xsl:if test="(position() mod 2 = 0)">
                          <tr class="rgAltRow SummaryTableDataRow">
                            <td valign = "top">
                              <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
                            </td>
                            <td valign = "top">
                              <xsl:value-of select="ConfId"/>
                            </td>
                            <td valign = "top">
                              <xsl:value-of select="CompositeAddress"/>
                            </td>
                            <td valign = "top">
                              <xsl:value-of select="CompositePort"/>
                            </td>
                            <td valign = "top">
                              <xsl:value-of select="CompositeSsrc"/>
                            </td>
                            <td valign = "top">
                              <xsl:value-of select="NoOfParticipants"/>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="(position() mod 2 = 1)">
                          <td>
                            <tr class="rgRow SummaryTableDataRow">
                              <td valign = "top">
                                <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
                              </td>
                              <td valign = "top">
                                <xsl:value-of select="ConfId"/>
                              </td>
                              <td valign = "top">
                                <xsl:value-of select="CompositeAddress"/>
                              </td>
                              <td valign = "top">
                                <xsl:value-of select="CompositePort"/>
                              </td>
                              <td valign = "top">
                                <xsl:value-of select="CompositeSsrc"/>
                              </td>
                              <td valign = "top">
                                <xsl:value-of select="NoOfParticipants"/>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </td>
                        </xsl:if>
                      </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                  </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:if test="MediaMixer = ''">
                    <td valign = "top">
                      <xsl:text>No Data </xsl:text>
                    </td>
                  </xsl:if>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          &#160;

          <div align="center">
            <b> Please select a Conference Name :</b>
           &#160;
            <select>
              <xsl:for-each select="MediaMixer/Conference">
                <option>
                  <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
                </option>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </select>
          </div>






          <table border="0" class="rgMasterTable rgClipCells" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
            <tr>
              <td class="rgHeader SummaryTableHdrRow" style="font-weight:bold;" colspan="2">Conference Details</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table border="0" class="rgMasterTable rgClipCells" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
                  <tr>
                    <td class="rgHeader SummaryTableHdrRow" style="font-weight:bold;">Conference Name</td>
                    <td class="rgHeader SummaryTableHdrRow" style="font-weight:bold;">Conference ID</td>
                    <td class="rgHeader SummaryTableHdrRow" style="font-weight:bold;">Participant ID 1</td>
                    <td class="rgHeader SummaryTableHdrRow" style="font-weight:bold;">Participant ID 2</td>
                    <td class="rgHeader SummaryTableHdrRow" style="font-weight:bold;">Participant Address</td>
                    <td class="rgHeader SummaryTableHdrRow" style="font-weight:bold;">Participant Listening Port</td>
                    <td class="rgHeader SummaryTableHdrRow" style="font-weight:bold;">MM Listening Port</td>
                    <td class="rgHeader SummaryTableHdrRow" style="font-weight:bold;">SSRC From Participant</td>
                    <td class="rgHeader SummaryTableHdrRow" style="font-weight:bold;">SSRC From MM</td>
                  </tr>
                  <xsl:if test="MediaMixer!= ''">
                    <xsl:for-each select="MediaMixer/Conference">
                      <xsl:for-each  select="Participant">
                        <xsl:if test="(position() mod 2 = 0)">
                          <tr class="rgAltRow SummaryTableDataRow">
                            <td valign = "top">
                              <xsl:value-of select="../Name"/>                            
                            </td>
                            <td valign = "top">
                              <xsl:value-of select="../ConfId"/>
                            </td>
                            <td valign = "top">
                              <xsl:value-of select="translate(ID1,
                                'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
                                'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')" />
                            </td>
                            <td valign = "top">
                                <xsl:value-of select="ID2"/>
                            </td>
                            <td valign = "top">
                              <xsl:value-of select="ParticipantAddress"/>
                            </td>
                            <td valign = "top">
                              <xsl:value-of select="ParticipantListeningPort"/>
                            </td>
                            <td valign = "top">
                              <xsl:value-of select="MMListeningPort"/>
                            </td>
                            <td valign = "top">
                              <xsl:value-of select="SSRCFromParticipant"/>
                            </td>
                            <td valign = "top">
                              <xsl:value-of select="SSRCFromMM"/>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="(position() mod 2 = 1)">
                          <td>
                            <tr class="rgRow SummaryTableDataRow">

                              <td valign = "top">
                                <xsl:value-of select="../Name"/>
                              </td>
                              <td valign = "top">
                                <xsl:value-of select="../ConfId"/>
                              </td>
                              <td valign = "top">
                                <xsl:value-of select="translate(ID1,
                                'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
                                'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')" />
                              </td>
                              <td valign = "top">
                                <xsl:value-of select="ID2"/>
                              </td>
                              <td valign = "top">
                                <xsl:value-of select="ParticipantAddress"/>
                              </td>
                              <td valign = "top">
                                <xsl:value-of select="ParticipantListeningPort"/>
                              </td>
                              <td valign = "top">
                                <xsl:value-of select="MMListeningPort"/>
                              </td>
                              <td valign = "top">
                                <xsl:value-of select="SSRCFromParticipant"/>
                              </td>
                              <td valign = "top">
                                <xsl:value-of select="SSRCFromMM"/>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </td>
                        </xsl:if>
                      </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                  </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:if test="MediaMixer= ''">
                    <td valign = "top">
                      <xsl:text>No Data </xsl:text>
                    </td>
                  </xsl:if>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          &#160;
          <div style="display:none">
            <iframe id="frameUpdate" name="frameUpdate" width="100%"></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[image]

I have a drop-down box that displays the Conference Names from the first table. What i want is, when i select a conference name, data relevant to it should be displayed in the second table. The data that is not relevant to a particular conference name should not be displayed. Right now, I am displaying all the data from the xml file.

How do i set a condition in xsl to display data based on my selection in the drop-down ?

Comment: There must be something that uniquely identifies a conference. What is it? In the provided XML document more than one conference have both the same ID and the same Name...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do i set a condition in xsl to display data based on my selection
>   in the drop-down ?

**Generally**:

You need to provide as a global (externally specified) parameter to the transformation a value that uniquely identifies the selected conference.

```
<xsl:param name="confUniqueId" select="someValueHere"/>
```

The value of this parameter is set by the code (JS in this case) that initiates the transformation -- you need to read the documentation to understand how exactly this must be done.

Then in your XSLT code, from the value of this parameter, identify the desired `Conference` element and apply templates only to this element.

Unfortunately, in the provided XML document more than one conference have both the same ID and the same Name...